# Place a large image in smaller screen resolutions without resizing

Tags: html, css, image, width

I want to place an image that is 1500px wide and I want this image to have its full size displayed in smaller screen resolutions, like 1024x768px. I don't want to use max-width: 100% because that will resize the image and that's exactly what I don't want. I want instead to  show its native resolution and "hide" the rest of the image. And the image cannot be a background.

Like this:

[image]

Thank you

Edit: Here's an example. I'm using Bootsrap 3. In smaller resolutions it breaks the page. I want it to be full-width without resizing it. The image is from Flickr. http://jsfiddle.net/a8T7J/1/embedded/result/

```
<section>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
            <img src="https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8083/8354311074_f961d5c489_h.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End row -->
</div>
<!-- End container -->
```

This is the code http://jsfiddle.net/a8T7J/1/

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Here's an example. I'm using Bootsrap 3. In smaller resolutions it breaks the page. I want it to be full-width without resizing it. The image is from Flickr. http://jsfiddle.net/a8T7J/1/embedded/result/ 

This is the code http://jsfiddle.net/a8T7J/1/

Answer (score 0):

you could use media queries to target specific screen resolutions

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 1024px) and (max-device-width : 1366px) {/* Styles */}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I don't want to crop the image, i want the image to display as if it was a full-width background, but it needs to be placed in the img tag.